# Tensorflow Layer mapping input to graph of regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to write a custom Keras layer which takes as input a d-dimensional vector x and outputs (x,Ax+b) where A is a trainable d by n matrix and n is a trainable n dimensional vector.

Here's what I've written but it's not seeming to work...

```
class custom_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(custom_layer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Defines A and b to be trainable
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.weight = self.add_weight(shape=input_shape[1], # CURRENTLY NOT A MATRIX FIX THIS!!!
                                    initializer='zeros',
                                    trainable=True)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=input_shape[1:],
                                    initializer='zeros',
                                    trainable=True)



    def call(self, x):
        # Apply Linear Regression
        x_out = tf.mat(x,self.weight) + self.bias
        # Concatenate map output with input to form  graph!
        x_out = tf.concat([x,x_out],-1)
        return x_out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all matrix multiplication is not commutative so (A X B) is not equal to (B X A), so tf.matmul(A,B) is not equal to tf.matmul(B,A).

Given input with dimension (d (batch size), n (vector length)), you want to apply your function Ax+b for every vector in the batch. Here is the code and output.

Input

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13.]]
```

Code

```
class custom_layer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(custom_layer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Defines A and b to be trainable
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.weight = self.add_weight(shape=(1,input_shape[1]),
                                    initializer='ones',
                                    trainable=True)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[0]),
                                    initializer='zeros',
                                    trainable=True)

        super(custom_layer, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, x):
        # Apply Linear Regression
        x_out = tf.matmul(self.weight,x,transpose_b=True) + self.bias
        # Concatenate map output with input to form  graph!
        x_out = tf.concat([x,tf.transpose(x_out)],-1)
        return x_out
```

Output

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6. 21.]
 [ 7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 70.]]
```

If you want to apply Ax+b element wise. Simple word, each element have its own weight and bias.

Input

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13.]]
```

Code

```
class custom_layer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(custom_layer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Defines A and b to be trainable
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.weight = self.add_weight(shape=(1,input_shape[1]),
                                    initializer='ones',
                                    trainable=True)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(1,input_shape[1]),
                                    initializer='zeros',
                                    trainable=True)

        super(custom_layer, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, x):
        # Apply Linear Regression
        x_out = tf.multiply(self.weight,x) + self.bias
        # Concatenate map output with input to form  graph!
        x_out = tf.concat([x,x_out],-1)
        return x_out
```

Output

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13.]]
```

**Edit**

Code for testing layer

```
test = custom_layer()
in1 = Input(shape=(7,))
out = test(in1)
# test
M = Model(inputs=[in1],outputs=[out])
M.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss='mse')
print(np.arange(14,dtype=np.float32).reshape(2,7))
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting this error when I try to compile the model:
'cutsom_layer' object has no attribute 'op'

when I compile the model using:
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=[2])
current_layer = custom_layer(input_layer)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[current_layer])
model.summary()

Comment: maybe you use it wrong, you try to pass ```input_layer``` to ```custom_layer``` instructor. what you need to do is create a layer first, ```current_layer = custom_layer()```, then connect it with input layer, ```output = current_layer (input_layer )```, and change model to ```model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[output])```

Comment: Makes sense but when I do this i recieve the error:
'current_layer' object has no attribute 'op'

Comment: I have provided my testing code, you can use it to figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: Thanks I've fixed it :)